# Oracle ORA-00902 Invalid datatype error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create two tables, which is throwing ORA-00902 error, can't figure out what's wrong here...

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_STORE
( 
  MODEL_NO VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
  UNIT_PRICE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  CURRENT_STOCK NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  CC NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,    
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_store_pk PRIMARY KEY(MODEL_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_BOOKING
( 
  BOOKING_ID VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL_ID VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  CONTACT NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
  PINCODE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  MODEL_NO VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  DATE_OF_BOOKING VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
  EXPECTED_DATE_OF_DELIVERY VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,  
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_booking_pk PRIMARY KEY(BOOKING_ID),
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_booking_fk FOREIGN_KEY(MODEL_NO) REFERENCES    VEHICLE_STORE(MODEL_NO)   
);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Get you the erro when creating the first table or when you creating the second table?

Comment: For the second table...

Comment: You should use an Oracle client that tells you the line number. Having to guess makes it all harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `FOREIGN_KEY(MODEL_NO)` to `FOREIGN KEY (MODEL_NO)` (no underscore).