# PL/SQL Passing a local collection into a pipelined function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I need to pass a locally defined table type to a function which is a pipelined function returning another locally defined table type.

Here is sample data:

```
create table my_tab
(i NUMBER,
 n VARCHAR2(30));

 insert into my_tab values (1, 'Peter');
 insert into my_tab values (2, 'Dakshesh');
 insert into my_tab values (1, 'Maggie');
 insert into my_tab values (3, 'Madhu');
 commit;
```

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg IS
    TYPE t_col IS RECORD(
    i NUMBER,
    n VARCHAR2(30));
    TYPE t_nested_table IS TABLE OF t_col;
    TYPE t_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    FUNCTION iterate_table RETURN t_number PIPELINED;
    FUNCTION return_table(in_t_num t_number) RETURN t_nested_table PIPELINED;
     g_number t_number ;
     g_nested_number t_nested_table ;
  END my_pkg;
  /
```

Body:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg IS
    FUNCTION iterate_table RETURN t_number PIPELINED IS
    BEGIN
      IF ( (g_number IS NOT NULL) AND (g_number.EXISTS (1)))
      THEN
         FOR i IN 1 .. g_number.COUNT
         LOOP
            IF g_number (i) IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               PIPE ROW (g_number (i));
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;
      RETURN;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RAISE;
   END iterate_table;

   FUNCTION return_table(in_t_num t_number) RETURN t_nested_table PIPELINED IS
      l_row t_nested_table ;
      CURSOR cur_test IS
          select mt.i, mt.n 
          from my_tab mt, TABLE(iterate_table ) tab
          where mt.i = tab.column_value;
     BEGIN
         OPEN cur_test;
         FETCH cur_test BULK COLLECT into l_row;
         CLOSE cur_test;
         FOR i IN 1..l_row.COUNT
         LOOP
             PIPE ROW(l_row(i));
         END LOOP;
         RETURN;
     END return_table;
 END my_pkg;
 /
```

Now this code compiles successfully, when I try to invoke it like a pipelined function, it gives error-

```
select * from table(my_pkg.return_table(my_pkg.t_number(1)));
```

Error-
`ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:

*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 41`

The two pre-requisites for this code are -

1. the collections should be all locally defined.
2. the function should be pipelined.

Help!!

I am not getting any error with table and its a single table so no foreign key constraints hold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle ORA-00902 Invalid datatype error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978942/oracle-ora-00902-invalid-datatype-error)

Comment: no... that is different.... I am not getting any error while creating the table and there is a single table only.. no violation of constraints.

Comment: also.. I am able to get the output if I print it using an anonymous block and dbms_output utility.

Comment: Are you sure that's your entire package? Line 14 appears to be the `END IF;`

Comment: A good solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779495/pipelined-function-calling-another-pipelined-function

Comment: I cant define the collections outside the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in oracle 11. I don't  know why oracle throws "invalid data type". 
If you put this query into anonymous block you will receive `PLS-00642: Local Collection Types Not Allowed in SQL Statement`

If you don't want or you cannot create sql level collection. The solution is use predefined type. Good source of predefined collection is `Oracle Data Cartridge`. Replace all `t_number` with `ODCINumberList`.

[predefined collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/ext_types_ref.htm#sthref778)

Comment: Not allowed to use the sys owned objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 10 and 11, it is not possible to use collections in the SQL scope that have been defined in a PL/SQL scope. [In Oracle 12](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10014), what you are trying should work.

If you want to do this then declare your types in the SQL scope (not in the package).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_col IS OBJECT(
  i NUMBER,
  n VARCHAR2(30)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_nested_table IS TABLE OF t_col;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg IS
  FUNCTION iterate_table RETURN t_number PIPELINED;
  FUNCTION return_table(in_t_num t_number) RETURN t_nested_table PIPELINED;
  g_number t_number ;
  g_nested_number t_nested_table ;
END my_pkg;
/
```

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi Mentioning that in your question would have been helpful. I've retagged the question to include the version.

Comment: will take care from next time... however, from all I have seen, this isn't possible in any version so far... further, there are a lot of constraints to what I am allowed to use and what not.